# Network communication between dedicated web and database server

Tags: java, database, networking, webserver

We're at the juncture (I can even say, right time) that we need to separate our database server apart from our application web server.  This we arrived at after careful & thorough monitoring of the server (load average, CPU usage, etc.) itself.

When the database server is separated:

1. What would be the ideal setup/best practice for network communication path between 2 servers?  If it were running on the same server, connectivity between database and application would make use of TCP/IP communication, but how it should be running/setup when it is separated, so that performance is not majorly affected?  For example, currently our JDBC URL looks like `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9999/ourproductiondb`, probably this `localhost` would be changed to private IP address of the database server.
2. In our application, we also allow application users to submit/attach attachments (.txt, .doc, .pdf, .xls, etc.), which are actually stored physically in server disk and only its file path is stored in the database.  Which is the ideal place/approach for maintaining/keeping documents physically, either in application web server or in database server?

We're very new into this area of separating database as a separate server and our knowledge on this is very limited.  Therefore, any resources, links, documentation, articles, guidelines, suggestion etc. in this regard are highly welcome and really appreciated.

**NOTE:** Our tools of trade are: RHEL5 64-bit, Apache Tomcat 6.0.10, JDK 1.6, PostgreSQL 8.2.22, pgpool 2.0.1

Answer (score 2):

I received a response for this very same question after posting in *serverfault*.  [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/326970/network-communication-between-dedicated-web-and-database-server/327145#327145) is the answer.  Am posting this as an answer here with the hope that this may be useful for other users who might have similar kind of question.